# AngularJS $rootScope.$on is not catching or pass data with Services via route

Tags: angularjs, controller, coffeescript

I want to send data from one controller to another. Actually i have followed this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/VxafF/)

My first Controller is like that:

```
class ProductCtrl

constructor: ($scope, @$log, @$location, @$timeout, @ProductService) ->   

    $scope.go = (path) =>
        $scope.$emit('handleEmit', @getAllProducts())
        $location.path path
```

Second one:

```
class UpdateProductCtrl

constructor: ($scope, @$log, @$routeParams) ->
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', (event, data) ->
        console.log(data)
    )
```

App.coffee:

```
app = angular.module('myApp', dependencies)
app.run ($rootScope, editableOptions) ->    
    $rootScope.$on 'handleEmit', (event, args) ->
        $rootScope.$broadcast 'handleBroadcast', args
```

Inside App coffee $rootScope.$on 'handleEmit' is not firing when i'll call $scope.$emit('handleEmit', @getAllProducts()) in ProductCtrl. Please help me what i did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comment on my other answer, I understand that the 2 controllers are on 2 different routes. Using events to communicate data won't work this way because when the first controller emits the event, the second has not yet registered its listener.

So, you need another way to pass data between routes. You could use a service to do that but since services are global objects, you need some kind scoping and maintanance of the data you are passing so that you don't accumulate junk or use stale data.

You could create a service acting like a global "storage" object with the following properties:

- It can accept data intended for the next route
- It can deliver data intended for the current route

This service, maintains internally two "buckets". All `put` operations are performed on the `nextRouteBucket` and all `get` operations are performed on the `currentRouteBucket`. When angular's router broadcasts the `$routeChangeStart` event, the service switches buckets and cleans up.

```
class NavScope
  constructor: ($rootScope) ->
    @currentRouteBucket = {}
    @nextRouteBucket = {}

    $rootScope.$on '$routeChangeStart', () =>
      @currentRouteBucket = @nextRouteBucket
      @nextRouteBucket = {}

  put: (name, data) ->
    @nextRouteBucket[name] = data

  get: (name) ->
    @currentRouteBucket[name]
```

The controller on the next route can simply call `navScope.get 'someKey'` to retrieve data from the previous route or retrieve them in a route `resolve` object (see plunker).

Keep in mind that this is just a prototype and there might be some corner cases like when the user navigates with browser "back" and "forward" or when routing fails. You always have to put associated ids on the URL so that if you don't find data on the `navScope`, retrieve them from the server.

Check out the plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SJMWFxxhxkdFt68Sbh8V?p=preview).

Comment: " Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:NavScopeProvider <- NavScope" error displayed on my console.What did i miss here?

Comment: Have you ever faced the following error "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: messageProvider <- message" in your "Route2Ctrl" ?

Answer (score 2):

I've made this [coffeescript plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JKI35yhjJnhA4tuP1vvo?p=preview) out of your code and it seems to be working fine. No CoffeeScript peculiarities, whatsoever.

Check that the `run` callback runs, indeed, or check for spelling errors in event names.

One suggestion, though: Whenever you need a "message bus" style of communication between controllers, prefer releasing events that live solely on `$rootScope` level. Having `$rootScope` broadcast events downwards can be expensive cause it has to traverse the whole scope hierarchy. Imagine the penalty where an `ng-repeat` somewhere in your page creates 500 child scopes. I know, it's procedural fors, whiles and ifs, but -in any case- it's code that does not need to run.

You can simply write:

```
app = angular.module('plunker', [])

class ProductCtrl
  constructor: ($scope, $rootScope) ->
    $scope.go = () ->
      $rootScope.$emit 'MyEvent', {message: 'Hello!'}

app.controller 'ProductCtrl', ProductCtrl

class UpdateProductCtrl
  constructor: ($scope, $rootScope) ->
    unsubscribe = $rootScope.$on 'MyEvent', (event, data) ->
      $scope.message = data.message
    $scope.$on '$destroy', unsubscribe

app.controller 'UpdateProductCtrl', UpdateProductCtrl
```

This way, `run` callback is not needed at all.
Check it out [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EYNcQc17XROnpQjUvJEO?p=preview).

Comment: Sure it`s working fine. I think the problem is that i'll open another page that`s why first controller is disappear imagically.